# Can I use replicate-ignore-db and replicate-do-table together?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to ignore one db out of a handful of dbs. I'm flagging 'replicate-ignore-db=foo' to ignore a specific db.

However, I want one table in foo to replicate. I flag 'replicate-do-table=foo.bar' to allow a table.

When using these options together replication does not update the slave at all.

The flowchart indicates that this should be possible: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules-table-options.html

Is it possible to ignore one db of many, while still allowing a table within the ignored db to replicate?

Comment: Does the master use `BINLOG_FORMAT=ROW`?  All bets are off, if not.

Answer (score 0):

imposible.
you can just type

```
replicate-do-table=foo.myTable
```

without `replicate-ignore-db=foo`